# Error adding ArcGIS MapServer Layer to QGIS 3.6?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, map-service

I have QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.6 installed on my machine (running Windows 10) and I am able to add ArcGIS MapServer Layers to my project in QGIS 2.18 without problems, but in QGIS 3.6, using the same services used in QGIS 2.18, it returns an error:

> Failed to retrieve service capabilities.
>   Network error: The proxy type is invalid for this operation

I'm using the Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer... tool to add the map service to the project.

Here's a printscreen of the creation of the connection to the ArcGIS MapService:

[image]

After clicking in the Connect button, it returns the following message:

[image]

Comment: Should go to ArcGIS Customer Support

Comment: I can't find any problem with the map service from ArcGIS Server to report to ESRI. Shouldn't the feature function in the same way in the two versions of QGIS? Could be something missing in the installation of QGIS 3.6?

Comment: https://gis.cm-lisboa.pt/arcgis/rest/services/Orto2011_ETRS89/MapServer works for me in QGIS 3.6. I'm on Windows 10 too

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks. It must be an installation issue then (I was trying to escape from debating with company's IT support, but no luck for me...)

Comment: you haven't `accidentally` got `Settings > Options > Use proxy for web access` set, or set and looking at some invalid proxy?

Comment: @nmtoken No. It is deactivated (as it is in QGIS 2.18, where I can access this map service)

Comment: I forgot to give feedback on this issue: reinstalling didn't fix the problem. The problem was solved setting the default proxy for Proxy Type: Settings > Options > Use proxy for web access (checked) > Proxy Type: DefaultProxy